# How to add binary file into Azure Function's Java Package

Tags: java, xml, azure, azure-functions

I'm currently trying to create Azure Function that runs ffmpeg binary in it. So far, I was able to run it locally by copying it to the target path in pom.xml. In local, I was able to run it using `Paths.get("")` to get current working directory and appending the binary path after it. I then execute it using Runtime's `exec()` method.

However, my method above does not work when I tried to run it on the Azure Function. When I try to list the contents of the current working directory in Azure Function, I can't find the binary folder / name in it...

Here's the part where I copied the ffmpeg binary in the pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-azure-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>                                    
                        <includes>
                            <include>host.json</include>
                            <include>local.settings.json</include>                               
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-ffmpeg-binaries</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/ffmpeg-binaries</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>ffmpeg-binaries</directory>                                    
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What might be missing in this command?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you can not work on azure?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Yes, I can't find the ffmpeg path on my cloud-hosted Azure, even after packaging them in my jar.

Comment: Are you sure you have successfully deployed the required packages? After the Azure Function is deployed, it will eventually be on kudu. First go to the kudu where you deployed the function, and then check D:\home\ site\wwwroot>. Is there any file you said? For your question, I think there are two possibilities: one is that the file is not successfully deployed, and the other is that the physical path is wrong.

Comment: Your function kudu: https://<yourfunctionname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Comment: @BowmanZhu I tried to log the contents of the D:\home\site\wwwroot, but I can't find my binary.... although other functionality still works fine. Any pointers where should I look for the physical path?

Comment: If you cannot find, that means the file upload failed. You can upload on hand to wwwroot. D:\home\ site\wwwroot> is the root directory of your azure function.